# Unexpected behavior AutoMapper mapping nested collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mapping, automapper

I'm trying to map types with nested collection using Mapper.Map(from, to); and I have encountered a number of issues.

Initially I had the issue where a property on my destination field which doesn't exist on my source type

```
 int Id {get; set; }
```

was always set to 0 regardless of what ForMember map I used (Ignore() or UseDestinationValue()). I discovered that I had to create a mapping for my collection types:

```
Mapper.CreateMap(List<source>, List<destination>)
```

This resulted in the id field not being set to 0, but now all values in my source collection are no longer copied to my destination collection. Below is an example of what I mean:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public virtual List<NestedTestModel> Models { get; set; }
}

public class NestedTestModel
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class TestEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<NestedTestEntity> Models { get; set; }
}

public class NestedTestEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

[Test]
public void TestMappingFromCalibrationModelToCalibrationModelEntity()
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<TestModel, TestEntity>()
        .ForMember(x => x.Id, x => x.UseDestinationValue());
    Mapper.CreateMap<NestedTestModel, NestedTestEntity>()
        .ForMember(x => x.Id, x => x.UseDestinationValue())
        .ForMember(x => x.Value, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.Value));
    Mapper.CreateMap<List<NestedTestModel>, List<NestedTestEntity>>();

    TestModel from = new TestModel();
    from.Models = new List<NestedTestModel>
    {
        new NestedTestModel { Value = 3 }
    };

    TestEntity to = new TestEntity
    {
        Models = new List<NestedTestEntity>
        {
            new NestedTestEntity { Id = 1, Value = 2 }
        }
    };

    var actual = Mapper.Map<TestModel, TestEntity>(from, to);

    // this only works if Mapper.CreateMap<List<NestedTestModel>, List<NestedTestEntity>>();
    Assert.AreEqual(1, actual.Models[0].Id);

    // Results in 
    // Expected: 3
    // But was:  2
    Assert.AreEqual(3, actual.Models[0].Value); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

AutoMapper supports collections so

```
Mapper.CreateMap(List<source>, List<destination>);
```

Is not required.

All you need is just:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<sourceNested, destinationNested>();
Mapper.CreateMap<source, destination>();
```

Then map like this:

```
var res = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<source>, IEnumerable<destination>>(source);
```

When mapping `TestModel` to `TestEntity` `TestEntity.Id` will **always** be `0` as it's type is `int` and default value for `int` is `0`.

Comment: Ok, I made the assumption that by using Mapper.Map<TestModel, TestEntity>(from, to); it would retain the values of the unmapped properties in the destination